# How to not include dependency in android library if not declared by app?

Tags: java, android, maven, dependencies, android-library

I'm working on a library for tracking views automatically in any android app. Of the many views which can be tracked is Recyclerview, which is not available natively in Android, so I have declared that dependency in the library.

`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'`

However, if some app uses my library but does not use a recyclerview, this dependency will still be included into the app.

**Is there some way to not include a dependency if it is not used by an app?**

*Things I've tried :*

- I declared the dependency using provided so that it is not included in the pom.xml and hence not downloaded when my library's dependency is added into an app.

  `provided 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'`

  But that throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error when the library executes.
- Added a if condition to check if the class exists using reflection before using the class in the library.

  ```
  public static boolean isClass(String className) {
      try  {
          Class.forName(className);
          return true;
      }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  ...

  if (Utils.isClass("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView")
              && child instanceof RecyclerView) {
      //adding listeners to RV
  }
  ```

  However, this too throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error when the library executes.

What are my options?